# "AttributeError: 'GoogleBaseHook' object has no attribute 'get_records'" Error while trying to run Custom SqlSensor for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, sensors, google-cloud-composer

I am migrating some DAG's from "Cloud Composer-1 Airflow-1" to Cloud "Composer-2 Airflow-2".

I have created a custom module called `BigQuerySqlSensor` acting like a `SqlSensor` for BigQuery.

I have done this by creating another custom module called `MySqlSensor` because Airflow has removed some of the supported attributes for `BaseHook` and recommended to use `DbApiHook` instead.

I have basically used the same source code of SqlSensor ([can be found here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/sql.html#SqlSensor)) and replaced `BaseHook` module with `DbApiHook`.

Then I used the `MySqlSensor` to create custom `BigQuerySqlSensor` like below:

```
class BigQuerySqlSensor(MySqlSensor):
    def _get_hook(self):
        hook = super()._get_hook()
        hook.use_legacy_sql = False
        return hook
```

The task where I am calling the `BigQuerySqlSensor` is:

```
task = BigQuerySqlSensor(
        task_id='my_task',
        conn_id='bigquery_default',
        timeout= <Some Numbers>
        poke_interval= <Some Numbers>
        mode='reschedule',
        sql='my_sql.sql'
    )
```

However, I am getting an error such as:

```
        records = hook.get_records(self.sql, self.parameters)
AttributeError: 'GoogleBaseHook' object has no attribute 'get_records'
```

I am not sure where `GoogleBaseHook` is being picked up. I am guessing it is something to do with the connection in Airflow.

In my previous Cloud Composer instance, I am running the same code with same configurations and connections. I am out of ideas at this point. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `GoogleBaseHook` instead of BigQueryHook (probably your connection type is `google_cloud_platform`).

It seems it can be solved by defining `gcpbigquery` connection - but base `SqlSensor` class checks type of hook and doesn't allow it (it looks like airflow bug - and it seems it is already solved on airflow `main` branch)

I solved it by defining my own sensor class this way:

```
class BigQuerySqlSensor(SqlSensor):
    def _get_hook(self):
        return BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id=self.conn_id, use_legacy_sql=False, location="us")
```

(conn_id is identifier of `google_cloud_platform` connection). This way you can also add additional hook parameters - it seems at least 'location' is required.

It works for me on Airflow 2.2.3

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrk! Creating a `gcpbigquery` connection worked well! I just had to change the `conn_id` value with `gcpbigquery` in the `BigQuerySqlSensor` task and add `hook.location = <location>` into the class

Answer (score 0):

To give a bit more details to @mrk's answer. Starting with [airflow 2.4.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#dbapihook-and-sqlsensor-have-moved-24836) `SqlSensor` has been moved into a new `airflow.providers.common` package so would want to check that you're doing `from airflow.providers.common.sql.sensors.sql import SqlSensor` rather than `from airflow.sensors.sql import SqlSensor`

For GCP, there can be multiple [connection types](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.5.2/airflow/providers/google/provider.yaml#L948). You'd want to make sure that your connection type is 'gcpbigquery' (since there can be multiple sql products on gcp to use sensor for)

You can check your connection type with

```py
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook
c = BaseHook.get_connection('bigquery_default') # name of connection
c.conn_type # should be gcpbigquery and not google-cloud-platform
```

You'll can find connection type in env specified something like `AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT='gcpbigquery://'` or somewhere in secrets