# BigQueryCheckOperator for sensor operations

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

The `BigQueryCheckOperator` in airflow just checks a bigquery query and fails and error out in case the query fails.

I don't find anything the equivalent sensor operator: it should check the bigquery query periodically and waits until the query returns True.

Is there any operator in airflow that does it? Only way I see to do it is to let the operator fails and set the retry parameter.

Comment: The relationship between the Bigquery task and the sensor in 2 separated DAGs ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. I am trying to understand how to make a sensor task that runs a bq query periodically until it returns True. All google provider operators can just run a query to check for a condition, but they just fail if it is not satistifed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic [`SqlSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/78b8ea2f22239db3ef9976301234a66e50b47a94/airflow/providers/common/sql/sensors/sql.py#L27) support BigQuery thus there is no need for dedicated BigQuery classes.

Example:

```
sense_data = SqlSensor(
    task_id="sensor",
    conn_id="gcpbigquery",
    hook_kwargs={"use_legacy_sql": False},
    sql="select count(1) > 0 from `dataset.table`",
    mode='reschedule',
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot find information whether or not this operator is deferrable though. Have you any idea about it? I am trying to make a sensor that check a query for many hours and I am trying to avoid having a worker task busy all time

Comment: For sensors you just need to use `mode='reschedule'` https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/sensors.html

Comment: I get an error with the `hook_kwargs` parameter: Invalid arguments were passed to SqlSensor; Invalid arguments were: **kwargs: {'hook_kwargs': {'use_legacy_sql': False}}

Comment: and removing it another one: `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The connection type is not supported by SqlSensor. The associated hook should be a subclass of `DbApiHook`. Got GoogleBaseHook`

Comment: Do you use latest common.sql + google providers?

Comment: I am using airflow 2.4, so it should have the most updated libraries

Comment: this happens if I use either `from airflow.sensors.sql import SqlSensor` or `from airflow.providers.common.sql.sensors.sql import SqlSensor`

Comment: Just found another stackoverflow question that is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71037231/attributeerror-googlebasehook-object-has-no-attribute-get-records-error-w . This custom operator `BigQuerySqlSensor` works

Comment: Please open GitHub bug report so we can invistigate https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues

Comment: Hi, apparently the problem is that one needs to define an airflow BigQuery connection type (gcpbigquery), not a google cloud type (google_cloud_platform). Anyhow, thank you for all your help

Comment: Yes, I edited answer to reflect that some time ago